# Available options for sending an email through windows 8 metro app?

Tags: email, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

i am developing an metro application , where i have requirement :-

where i need to send some information from my app to end users through an email, i am generating the information or content for  that email programatically through code.

**Firstly** thing i worked on is **launching mailto app** in my application in this way :-

```cs
using Windows.System;

//starts the default mail app with a subject, cc, bcc, and body
Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("mailto:windows8devs@almostbeta.com?subject=Code Request&cc=kevin@almostbeta.com&bcc=admin@almostbeta.com&body=Hi!"));
```

Then i discovered that i cannot attach attachements to this mail app programatically 
through code if you are launching the mail app in this way.

**Secondly**, i worked on **share contract** where i can share content generated from my app to other apps (like mailto app also...)

and i was able to share my content successfully which means :-

using this i am able to attach a file(which i generated through code) to mailto app and if i specify the mail address and send it it works fine and delivered successfully )

But now i discovered that i cannot set the subject or body of the mail app to which i am sharing content , if i am using an share contract to share files.

**so my doubt is** :-

1) first of all , is there any way that i can set the subject or body of the mail app to which i am sharing content , if i am using an share contract to share files ??

2)Am i missing any other alternative / are there any other possible ways  of sending email using metro app ??

3)if not , what is the workaround through which i can achieve my goal ( sending an email through which i can attach file programatically through code and have a body , subject set to it )

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly when using the share contract it's up to the share target to decide how the values you are setting are going to be used. You don't have any control over that. As you've noticed the built-in mail client doesn't use the other shared values when you're adding an attachment.

The only alternative I can think of is to send the mail directly from your code using SMTP. The downside is that there's no `SmtpClient` class in .NET for Windows Store apps and neither could I quickly find another .NET implementation of this functionality that you could use, so it seems you're on your own here. Also in this case you'd need the user to configure his SMTP server in your application.

Considering all that the best approach would probably be to take care of sending emails in the online component of your application, i.e. you create a service and host it somewhere. You then send the data for the mail from the app to your service and send the mail from there using the regular .NET `SmtpClient`.

Comment: Microsoft will heavily advise against automatically sending emails via SMTP, and I doubt it would even pass certification. One of the major goals with Windows Store Apps is to keep the user in complete control of what is happening. Setting up a WCF service is one way to achieve this goal without compromising the design guidelines of Windows Store Apps.

Comment: @Justing How is accessing WCF service different form using SMTP protocol? What about creating email client for Windows App store?

Comment: I think too it is great miss. a lot of productivity apps can benefit not only from using documents but emails also. it is very unfortunate that sinofski didnt get that. shame really

Answer (score 2):

I have mostly good news for you:

1. You can open the Win-RT mail app and prepare an email using mailto.

   `Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("mailto:[email]?subject=[subject]&body=[body]?"));`
2. See 1
3. Best bet for this one is to upload the file somewhere and send the email with the link to the attachment in the body of the email

For other mail properties check out:

http://email.about.com/library/misc/blmailto_encoder.htm

Hope it helps!

Comment: This will work, but there appears to be a limit to the size of the body used in the URI for the Windows 8 Mail app. It's probably similar to the limit in Outlook (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6604542/1428388).