# HYPERLINK to e-mail: How to insert a long &body?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to send e-mails with a pre-set subject and a pre-set body.
I'm using the following code

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:email@mail.com?subject=Test subject&body=Test body","Send email")
```

It works well but I would like to send a very long body. Unfortunately, seems like there is a character limit.

I need to send the emails from an email client, not from Gmail

Comment: how long is "long" ?

Comment: Long enough to not letting it open the email client. When I try with a short message, it's alright but with long messages nothing happens when I click on the link

Comment: It seems that there are limits for maximum `mailto:` url length that depend on your email client: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473959/effective-maximum-mailto-body-lengths In this case you you might consider changing the email client send your email / create a draft with a [script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail).