# Is it possible to add mailto body lengths?

Tags: html

In order to Send Email.
So I using Mailto to achieve my aim.

```
<a href="mailto:abc@gmail.com?subject=Hello&body=How are you?%20">Send email</a>
```

When the `body=` has too much text
the send email button is no response.......

but it is working on a few texts.

Is it possible to add mailto body lengths??

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473959/effective-maximum-mailto-body-lengths