# Can I use javascript to populate mailto email?

Tags: javascript, mailto

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mailto link for large bodies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857/mailto-link-for-large-bodies)

I'm making a basic CRM system.

The user can save/edit his email signature by using a rich text editor - which is then saved into a mysql table.

Then when the user clicks on customers email, using mailto it opens an email to that customer.

Is there a way to then have his saved signature in that email?

I know about the &body= thing but that can only handle 256 characters and lines and spaces have to be coded in.

I was wondering if there's a way to do it with javascript?

Comment: This does not really have anything to do with Javascript just so you know.

Comment: oh, would the solution (if there is one) not involve javascript?

Comment: Well since he asked if he could use JS to accomplish this, then I'd say the JavaScript tag is fair

Comment: No, JS can only create the same elements and `href`-attributes as serverside-created html tags.

Comment: @KevinBoucher I am not trying to rag on him for including it, I totally understand where he is coming from. It's just that the question is not really about Javascript, it is about the anchor tag with `mailto`.

Comment: When the page is rendered out, can you use something like php (or whatever your using) to populate the &body= based on that users token? Seems like it would be easier then using JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **No**. Javascript can not change the way external programs interpret link protocols.

Javascript can however populate the link destination with dynamic content, but it can’t get around the usual browser limits that follows.